# php - how to get xml attribute from object

Tags: php, xml

web-service return me this code -

```
    global  $s;
    global  $params;
    $s = new soapclient($conDetails['url'],array('wsdl'));
    $params = new stdClass;
    $paramsStr = ' 
                    <LoginInput>
                        <LoginRec Action="SuppAuthn" UserEmail="'.$email.'" UserPass="'.$password.'" />
                    </LoginInput>
                ';
    $params->xmlRequest = $paramsStr;

    $result = $s->__call("SubmitXmlString",array($params));
```

when i print the results it get:

```
echo "<pre>".(var_dump($result,true))."</pre>";


object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
    ["SubmitXmlStringResult"]=> string(496) 
    "<LoginOutput>
        <Login UsrId="XX" UsrName="Some Name" SessionId="10" supplierCode="2" supplierName="Supp name" supplierEmail=""/>
        <Countries>
            <country code="DE" name="Germany"/>
            <country code="ES" name="Spain"/>
            <country code="FR" name="France"/>
        </Countries>
    </LoginOutput>
" } bool(true)
```

How do i get "supplierCode" value for the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { 
    ["SubmitXmlStringResult"]=> string(496)
```

So you have an object with a property called `SubmitXmlStringResult` that contains a `string` which is valid XML. So you use `simplexml_load_string` on that data. Once you have that, you can see the `supplierCode` is an attribute of the `Login` element. Thus, you can get that this way:

```
<?php
// Recreating your variable
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->SubmitXmlStringResult =<<<ENDXML
<LoginOutput>
    <Login UsrId="XX" UsrName="Some Name" SessionId="10" supplierCode="2" supplierName="Supp name" supplierEmail=""/>
    <Countries>
        <country code="DE" name="Germany"/>
        <country code="ES" name="Spain"/>
        <country code="FR" name="France"/>
    </Countries>
</LoginOutput>
ENDXML;

// Load the XML from the object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($obj->SubmitXmlStringResult);
// Get supplierCode attribute from Login element
$supplierCode = $xml->Login->attributes()['supplierCode'];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I edited my post. can you please update your respond?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get only `XML` from your class object and need to set that in a variable. Then you need to create an `XML` object and then can access `supplierCode` as below:

```
$xmlString = $result->SubmitXmlStringResult;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
echo $xml->Login[0]->attributes()->supplierCode;
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I edited my post. can you please update your respond?

Comment: ECHO doesn't print anything. I

Comment: sure - `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["UserEmail"]=> string(17) "email@gmail.com" } ["NewDataSet"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["Table"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"]=> string(266) "" } } } `